# Как обновлять массив в реальном времени, а не после обновления страницы (Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, localstorage, jsx

Я пытаюсь реализовать туду лист и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Я хочу реализовать функционал в котором при клике на чекбокс текст будет зачёркиватьcя. Для этого в объекте дела у меня есть значение isDone  которые по дефолту false а при клике  становится true. Я использую React-redux и  для того чтобы state записывался в localStorage  использую плагин redux-persist. Но сейчас  если я кликну то состояние обновится только после перезагрузки страницы.

У меня есть checkbox при клике на которой он принимает массив с делами и текст того дела на которой мы нажали

input

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={value.isDone}
  onChange={()=>this.props.done(this.props.deals,value.text)} 
/> 
//this.props.deals - масив с делами, value.text - текст дела 
//deals":[{"text":"test","isDone":false}] - Вот так он выглядит
```

Далее в Action я принимаю етот массив и текст дела. Ищу дела по которым ми кликнули по тексту и меняю значение isDone на false если true и наоборот. Потом перезаписываю этот массив.

Action

```
    export function done(deals,dealText){
        return(dispatch) =>{
            deals.map(value=>{
                if(value.text === dealText){
                    value.isDone = !value.isDone
                }
            })
            dispatch(doneDeal(deals));
        }
    }

    export function doneDeal(deals){
        return{
            type: DONE,
            deals
        }
    }
```

Reducer

```
const initialState ={
    value: "",
    deals: []
}

case DONE:
   return { 
         ...state, deals: action.deals
   }
```

Если нужно больше информации сообщите  и я её дам. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1) Если компонент функциональный.

---

```
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [props.deals])
```

2) Если компонент это class

---

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     if (prevProps.deals !== this.props.deals) { 
   }
}
```